# error while i send request from postman to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, postman

my backend is running and im connected to mongoDB but when i send a post request from postman i get this error, i also put my network access to 0.0.0.0/0 (from anywhere) i have no idea by now what may cause this error.

this error is in my terminal:

> Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 18.194.195.125:27017
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {   name: 'MongoNetworkError' }

and i get this error in postman:

> 500Internal Server Error

this is my api index file:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");

dotenv.config();
app.use(express.json());

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
  }).then(console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);

app.listen("5000", () => {
    console.log("Backend is running.");
  });
```

and here is my auth file:

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

//REGISTER
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // making password hash
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
    const newUser = new User({
      username: req.body.username,
      email: req.body.email,
      password: hashedPass,
    });

    const user = await newUser.save();
    res.status(200).json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

and my user file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    profilePic: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Comment: is your mongo is getting connected from your shell or compass. as it seems your connection is getting timedout

Answer (score 0):

Check that your backend manages to connect to MongoDB. 
Look for connection logs in your mongod terminal if you're running a server  locally and check your connection string ( eg. mongodb://localhost:27017/db )